# safe php template engine

Tags: php, template-engine

I finding a php template engine allow user defined function only or it allow white-list functions only. My problem is I will let my user edit their templates. So I need a safe template engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The twig project ( http://www.twig-project.org/ ) has a sandbox mode.

Answer (score 1):

Rain implements the sandbox with black_list, if you ask they might add the white list as well
http://www.raintpl.com/

Comment: +1 for Rain. We are using it today in the development of many solid and big projects. The team of developers love it, and it's simplicity (in addition to performance and security) is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need conditions(if), loops(for) and filters maybe my minimal Text-Template class could do the job: https://github.com/dermatthes/text-template

It's pure regular expressions without the need for filesystem access nor eval()'d code. So it should be quite secure. And it'll parse 50kB of template within <3ms.